# Alternative OS for Nokia XR20

Tags: operating-system, nokia

Does anyone know any existing OS (other than Android) that works for Nokia Xr20. or if not, is it fairly quick to Port an existing OS for this phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though unfortunately no custom ROMs are available for that device, booting an Android GSI or Generic System Image is a good possibility if you somehow manage to unlock the bootloader of that device.